# Bluetooth being turned on after each restart on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I never use bluetooth on my laptop and disable it through the menu on top right corner but it is being turned on again after each restart. There is no physical button on my laptop to turn it on and off as well. It wasn't happening few weeks ago but I think latest update caused this to happen.

How can I disable it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to disable the service that controls Bluetooth:

0. Open a Terminal (if one is not already open)
1. Disable the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
   ```

Done. Now Bluetooth will remain disabled until you re-enable it with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
```